# The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found and The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code for generating excel file is as follows:

```
protected void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
Session["institute"] = "ABC";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from alumni_details where institute_name='" + Session ["institute"].ToString () + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds); 
GenerateXLSXFile(ds .Tables [0]);
}
catch (Exception)
{
 throw;
}
}
```

The function which generate excel report when i am calling this function i get the above errors

```
private void GenerateXLSXFile(DataTable tbl)
{
dynamic excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
dynamic excelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DemoPage");
excelWorksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `dynamic` keyword to workaround the initial problem. Add a reference to `EPPLus` in your project and a `using OfficeOpenXml;` at top of the file.

Comment: i am using .net framework2.0

Comment: Well that's your issue. `dynamic` is a .NET 4 keyword.

Comment: @Arran: `dynamic` is a C#4.0 keyword, although its implementation relies on new features in .net 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `dynamic` keyword to workaround the initial problem. [Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to `EPPLus` in your project and a `using OfficeOpenXml;` at top of the file.

So either:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
// ...
ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
```

or

```
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage excelPackage = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
```

Btw, here is another bug, replace

```
excelWorksheet.Cells("A1")
```

with

```
excelWorksheet.Cells["A1"]...
```

I assume this was converted from VB.NET to C#.

Comment: but this namespace is not in the asp.net c#

Comment: @HiteshKasar: But you are using `ExcelPackage` which is [`EPPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). So no, it's not a class in the .NET framwework.

Comment: So is there any setup through which i can give a reference and continue my work?

Comment: @HiteshKasar: I have provided the link to MSDN in my answer where you can see how to add references. Just click on [download](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and add the reference, then add the `using OfficeOpenXml` or use the full path to the class.

Comment: now these two errors occured if i replaced ExcelPackage instead of dynamic  1.Cannot implicitly convert type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet' to 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage'
   2. 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage' does not contain a definition for 'Cells'

Comment: @HiteshKasar: For the second error, i have edited my answer. I assume you have converted this from VB.NET to C#. You access array in VB with `()` and in C# with `[]`. According to the first error, it's not obvious where you are using a `ExcelWorksheet` as `ExcelPackage`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter-now this error occured if i replaced ExcelPackage instead of dynamic  1.'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Cells' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method' for 'Cells'

Comment: @HiteshKasar: Have you seen my last comment and my last edit of my answer??

Comment: @TimSchmelter-yup got it....thnQ....  
TimSchmelter-now if possible then please tell me how to format that excel file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter-can we give header and title to that excel sheet

Comment: @HiteshKasar: Sorry, but it's difficult to help you from comments. Ask another question and provide all necessary informations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570475/how-can-we-give-header-and-title-to-excel-sheet-in-asp-net-in-following-function

Answer (score 2):

The `dynamic` keyword is part of .NET Framework 4.0 and later.

Verify you are targeting .NET Framework 4.0 or later.

Comment: but now can you tel me the solution

Answer (score 0):

dynamic resides in System namespace. you should add `using System` at the top.

and for ExcelPackage `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`